# Government Patent Licensing Rights

Tags: licensing, patents

If a license is issued to the US Government to build and operate a patented measurement system, is it violation of the license if the government hires a contractor to build and operate the system?

Any questions to confine the scope of the question are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Licenses are not standardized. The terms of the particular license would dictate whether that activity was allowed.